# Flash Player crashes after accessing to camera

Tags: windows, crash, webcam, adobe-flash

I'm making a flash which is using camera (like `video.attachCamera(camera);`), and it works perfectly well.

However, when I close flash player and try to edit flash(fla), it crashes every time.

If I open the flash(swf) using Flash Player, a popup telling "Adobe Flash has crashed" appears  **after** I close the player. When I'm working with Adobe Flash CS5, entire Flash CS5 crashes after I close the player.

```
Problem Event Name: BEX
Application Name:   FlashPlayer.exe
Application Version:    10.1.52.14
Application Timestamp:  4b9e96ec
Fault Module Name:  StackHash_0a9e
Fault Module Version:   0.0.0.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 00000000
Exception Offset:   0000e100
Exception Code: c0000005
Edception Data: 00000008
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.768.3
Locale ID:  1042
Additional Information 1:   0a9e
Additional Information 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Additional Information 3:   0a9e
Additional Information 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I'm using ASUS K52J laptop and its webcam. What cause this problem? I try to update flash player but the site says about Google Chrome Flash Player Plugin, saying "Your flash player is automatically updated by Google Chrome automatically."

Only solution I found was recovering... How to fix this problem?

Comment: Make sure you have the latest version of Chrome, too.

Comment: @grawity I have Google Chrome 14.0.803, but I think that's not the problem..

Comment: It's not, but Chrome is supposed to have at least Flash 10.3 by now, even the "stable" version.